React Native with Expo, PHP WebSocket connection
I am developing a mobile application and I would like to send notifications to the relevant users when there is a change in a database table. To achieve this, I have tried to create a WebSocket server that listens to the database and notifies the frontend, which then sends notifications even when the application is closed. However, my frontend is unable to connect to the WebSocket server. Here is the error:

LOG WebSocket error: {"isTrusted": false, "message": "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused"}
LOG WebSocket is closed.

I am new to mobile development and I have never created a socket server before.
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use React\EventLoop\Loop;
use Ratchet\App;

class DatabaseWatcher implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;
    protected $lastMaxId;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->lastMaxId = $this->getMaxId(); 
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn, ['ref_restaurant' => null]);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        
        $data = json_decode($msg, true);
        if (isset($data['ref_restaurant'])) {
            $this->clients[$from]['ref_restaurant'] = $data['ref_restaurant'];
            echo "Client {$from->resourceId} set ref_restaurant to {$data['ref_restaurant']}\n";
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }

    public function getMaxId()
    {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=193.203.168.77;dbname=u440859155_db_yumeats', 'u440859155_yumeats', 'YumEats2024@');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM orders');
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $result['max_id'] ?? 0;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Database error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public function checkDatabase()
    {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=193.203.168.77;dbname=u440859155_db_yumeats', 'u440859155_yumeats', 'YumEats2024@');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id > :lastMaxId');
            $stmt->execute(['lastMaxId' => $this->lastMaxId]);
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if (!empty($rows)) {
                $this->lastMaxId = max(array_column($rows, 'id'));
                echo "New entries found:\n";
                print_r($rows); // Log the new entries
                foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
                    $clientRestaurant = $this->clients[$client]['ref_restaurant'];
                    $filteredRows = array_filter($rows, function ($row) use ($clientRestaurant) {
                        return $row['ref_restaurant'] === $clientRestaurant;
                    });

                    if (!empty($filteredRows)) {
                        $client->send(json_encode($filteredRows));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Database error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
}

$app = new Ratchet\App('0.0.0.0', 8080);
$loop = Loop::get();

$databaseWatcher = new DatabaseWatcher();
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function () use ($databaseWatcher) {
    $databaseWatcher->checkDatabase();
});

$app->route('/database-watcher', $databaseWatcher, ['*']);
$app->run();


const ws = useRef(null); 

const initializeWebSocket = (refRestaurant) => {
    ws.current = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/database-watcher');
    
    ws.current.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket is connected.');
        ws.current.send(JSON.stringify({ ref_restaurant: refRestaurant }));
    };
    
    ws.current.onmessage = (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('Received data:', data);
        setOrdersAndClients(prevOrders => [...prevOrders, ...data]); 


        Alert.alert(
            "Nouvelle commande",
            "Une nouvelle commande a été reçue.",
            [{ text: "OK" }]
        );
    };
    
    ws.current.onclose = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket is closed.');
    };
    
    ws.current.onerror = (error) => {
        console.log('WebSocket error:', error);
    };
};


Why re-invent the wheel? expo-notifications provides a generic API adapter to FCM and FCM's APN interface which even supports acknowledgements for offline capabilities.

@Jaquarh But how can we send a notification when there is a change in the database? Note that the database is in MySQL.

PHP does not know if there is a change in the database... unless PHP is commiting the change to the database... So if you're using a framework like laravel, you can just hook onto the saved event or if you're not using a framework, you'll need to build this logic yourself??

You should use localhost when you create your Ratchet\App object, not 0.0.0.0.

As @Jaquarh commented, you can use expo-notifications to manage your notifications.
When an activity has occured in your database it means that some query was made. You can add a script to send a push notification when that query is made.
You can use this expo-server-sdk-php to manage push notifications in your PHP code.
Example:
<?php

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

use ExpoSDK\Expo;
use ExpoSDK\ExpoMessage;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$query = "INSERT INTO users(name, gender) VALUES(?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, $gender);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {

        // Example push tokens. You could build a query to get users expo tokens from your DB
        $recipients = [
            'ExponentPushToken[xxxx-xxxx-xxxx]',
            'ExponentPushToken[yyyy-yyyy-yyyy]'
        ];

        $messages = [
            new ExpoMessage([
                'title' => "New users connected!!!",
                'body' => "New users are now connected with you!"
            ])
        ];
        $expoSend = new Expo();
        $expoSend->send($messages)->to($recipients)->push();

        echo json_encode(array("response" => "success"));
    }

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();


Ref: Expo push notifications
